# Convert arthmetic formulae to sql code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i need to add sum and isnull to some string like below.

and this need to be done dynamically user only enter arthmetic string and i need to convert this into sql like code
please help

airthmetic formulae :

```
    col1/((col1+(col2-col3))/col4)
```

sqlcode :

```
    sum(isnull(col1,0)/((sum(isnull(col1,0))
    +(sum(isnull(col2,0))-
    sum(isnull(col3,0))))/sum(isnull(col4,0)) )
```

Comment: Not really 100% sure what you're asking. You want these calculations to be stored dynamically in a variable?

Comment: i need to show sql code only, user inputs his formulae and i want to show sql query and then might be i need to fire this query on proper table.

Comment: from what I can see you can just replace each column name with...COALESCE(cilumnName,0) and prefix SELECT and then run the sql with EXEC(SQLCOMMAND)

Comment: The only thing you are changing in the 'conversion' process seems to be that you surround each mention of `col<n>` with `sum(isnull(col<n>,0))`. Wouldn't that be a typical regex type of job?

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Just write an expression parser. Hand it your input expression and then walk down the resulting parse tree replacing appropriate symbols with your subexpression of choice whilst generating TSQL script. On the way through you can validate the column names against those in your table/view/etc. Not something that TSQL is going to handle easily.

Answer (score 0):

To do this dynamically you would need to declare variables such as

```
    DECLARE @SUM1 int


    SET @SUM1 = sum(isnull(col1,0)/(((sum(isnull(col1,0))
                +(sum(isnull(col2,0))-
                sum(isnull(col3,0)))))/sum(isnull(col4,0)) )
```

This would be dynamic but most likely wouldnt work.

What are your expected results and i could create better code

Comment: i need to add sum(isnull(,0)) in alll coulmn this is sample string there could be thousand of string like this and i need  to do this by query not manually each query.

Comment: yes, input would be like :  col1/((col1+(col2-col3))/col4) and output requires like : sum(isnull(col1,0)/((sum(isnull(col1,0))
    +(sum(isnull(col2,0))-
    sum(isnull(col3,0))))/sum(isnull(col4,0)) )

there could be any sort of input string and  i want to find out column and add sum and isnull at apppropriate places.